# Spark-Cassandra-Connector Does not work for spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-cassandra-connector to connect to cassandra from spark.

I am able to connect through Livy successfully using the below command.

```
curl -X POST --data '{"file": "/my/path/test.py", "conf" : {"spark.jars.packages": "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.0", "spark.cassandra.connection.host":"myip"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/batches
```

Also able to connect through pyspark shell interactively using below command

```
sudo pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:2.0.10 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=myip
```

**However not able to connect through spark-submit. some of the commands I have tried for the same are below.**

`spark-submit test.py --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.2 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=myip` this one didnt work.

I tried passing these parameters my python files used for spark-submit, still didnt work.

`conf = (SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-Cassandracube").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","myip").set({"spark.jars.packages","com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.0"))`

`sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)`
`sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)`

tried passing these parameters uisng jupyter notebook was also.

`import os`

`os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host="myip" pyspark-shell'`

All the threads that i have seen so far are talking about spark-cassandra-connector using spark-shell but nothing much about spark-submit.

Version used

Livy : 0.5.0
Spark : 2.4.0
Cassandra : 3.11.4

Comment: what spark version do you have

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but the most probable cause is that you're specifying all options:

```
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.2 \
  --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=myip
```

after a name of your script: `test.py` - in this case, `spark-submit` considers them as parameters for a script itself, not for `spark-submit`. Try to move script name after options...

P.S. See [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/submitting-applications.html) for more details...

Comment: you are right. particularly, when we are passing packages and jars the script should be kept at the end of the command. Its a bit peculiar though. Thank you very much.

Comment: programs themselves are often require options, so this positional separation make it's easier to understand what parameters are belong to `spark-submit` and what to program itself